# Windows Azure: renew Virtual machine from trial

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I had one testing VM hosted on Windows Azure under Trial subscription. My trial ended on Tuesday and I paid for the pay-as-you-go today and I discovered that I can't again easily turn on the VM.

Is here any way how to take the machine from Trial subscription and put it to my current subscription?
Or just easily turn it on?

This is how my virtual machines dashboard looks like:
[image]

I want to avoid to recreate the whole VM again.
Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trial goes off and you want to continue in using the Windows Azure, you have to start pay for it. This means, buy on of them [subscriptions](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/). After purchasing a subscription, in my case it was pay-as-you-go subscription, **you have to (!!!) contact support by creating Support ticket** and ask for migrating your servers from Trial subscription to your new subscription.

Fortunately, the support works pretty fast and this whole transition had taken only about two hours. But still, this is silly solution from MS.